# What can cause delay in SELECT statement execution and high ASYNC_NETWORK_IO even with "disregard results after execution"

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2017, waits

We are facing performance problems on our SQL Servers.

7 servers, all running the same application, all have the same problem.

```
SELECT @@VERSION
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU19) (KB4535007) - 14.0.3281.6 (X64)   Jan 23 2020 21:00:04   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

When you look at the acummulated total server wait statistics the show 99% ASYNC_NETWORK_IO. We first assumed that this was caused by the application. However:

When we take query (captured from the application) and run it as a test from within SSMS with **disregard results after execution**. It takes about 6 seconds when we run it over a TCP connection and 50 seconds over a Named pipes connection. We get very slow results.

(without **disregard results after execution** the query gives a result of 57k rows 227 columns and a size of 221MB.)

It's core edition so we can't use a local connection. We tested connecting remotely with both TCP and Named pipes.

**over TCP**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 4 ms, elapsed time = 4 ms.

(57844 rows affected)
Table 'STORE-CUW01$Item'. Scan count 1, logical reads 14774, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1359 ms,  elapsed time = 6868 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

[image]

So even though though it only takes 0.62 seconds for the clustered index scan to complete, it still takes 6.8 seconds to complete the query even though **disregards results after execution is checked**

**Over Named Pipes**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(57844 rows affected)
Table 'STORE-CUW01$Item'. Scan count 1, logical reads 14774, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1578 ms,  elapsed time = 54202 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

[image]

With Named pipes it's even worse. Again it only takes half a second for the clustered index scan to complete and it takes 54 seconds for the query to complete.

If I restore the database to my laptop and run the same query I get 0.4 seconds for the clustered index scan and 1375ms CPU time, 1462ms elapsed time.

by using https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-wait-stats-for-a-single-operation/

I collected the wait stats for both the test with a TCP connection and Named Pipe connection:

**TCP**

[image]

**Named Pipes**

[image]

The wait's don't add up tot the total elapsed time. Only 0.472 seconds waittime and 6.8 elapsed time on the tcp test and only 40.7 Waittime vs 54.2 elapsed time on the Naped Pipe test.

further relevant info

- The SQL Servers are virtual servers VMware
- It's windows core edition
- 4 cores
- 64GB ram, only 16 GB assigned to SQL Server
- The application service is running on the same server as SQL Server
- The application itself connects with MARS Sessions

We don't understand where the time delay is coming from. Shouldn't the query complete much faster if you have disgard results checked?

Comment: What is your "performance problem"?  Wait stats alone are not a symptom.

Comment: Hi David, the query performance much slower on these servers than on my laptop. I trying to understand what is causing that. While executing on a tcp connection the total time is 6.8 seconds. Yet I only have 1359ms CPU time and 472 waittime. I'm trying to find an explanation in why it's taking 7 seconds. I'm also keen on understanding why the same query takes 8 times longer on a Named Pipes connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Results are still returned to the client with the discard results option. The large `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` wait time with discard results suggests network latency returning 221MB of data. I suggest you focus your troubleshooting on network rather than query plans.

Try a simple test by copying an 200MB file from the SQL machine to the client to see if you get similar times.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for taking the time to answer. I was unaware of the fact that "disregard result ater execution" still transfers the data to the client application. What still confuses me is that collecting the waitstats for the session only collects 472 ms NETWORK_IO. While, if the total 6.8 seconds that it take for the query to complete is bound by network performance, I would expect NETWORK_IO waits to accumulate close to 6.8 seconds. Could it be that collecting waitstats by extended events for a single sessions, doesn't catch all waittime?

Comment: Try using sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats instead of XEvents.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for that tip. using the dmv, I can see  5187ms ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waittime accumulated for the session after the query executed.  now the numbers match with the fact that network performance is slow. (Which is the case in this environment).